# My Graph Implementation In Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph

I have implemented a graph based on theory, and I'd like some advice regarding best practice, and thoughts about what i didn't implement that would make it even more useful, along with ideas that are supposed to be in graphs, but i missed them. I have included documentation in the code, to explain what each function does, and hopefully that is enough to explain my doings.

```
# Unweighted Graph
import itertools
class Graph:
    def __init__(self, array=None):
        """
        initialises the graph, with all the nodes
        keeps count on the number of nodes in graph

        if array is included as an argument, it inserts all the nodes in the array.
        """
        self.graph = dict()
        self.num_of_nodes = 0
        self.num_of_edges = 0
        if array:
            for val in array:
                self.insert_node(val)


    def __str__(self):
        """
        Displays the graph in this FORMAT: (adjacency list)

        node1 -> connected_nodes
        node2 -> node1 node3 node4
        """
        arr = list()
        for node, connected_nodes in self.graph.items():
            arr.append(f"{node} ---> {' '.join(list(map(str, connected_nodes)))}")
        return "\n".join(arr)


    def insert_node(self, value):
        """
        inserts a node to the graph
        """
        self.graph[value] = set()
        self.num_of_nodes += 1


    def check_node_exist(self, node):
        """
        checks for the existence of a node in the graph
        """
        if node in self.graph:
            return True
        raise Exception(f"Node {node} doesn't exist in the Graph")


    def create_undirected_edge(self, node1, node2):
        """
        creates an undirected edge between two nodes
        """
        if self.check_node_exist(node1) and self.check_node_exist(node2):
            self.graph[node1].add(node2)
            self.graph[node2].add(node1)
        self.num_of_edges += 1


    def create_directed_edge(self, from_node, to_node):
        """
        creates a directed edge from a node, to a node.
        """
        if self.check_node_exist(from_node) and self.check_node_exist(to_node):
            self.graph[from_node].add(to_node)
        self.num_of_edges += 1


    def connect_all_together(self):
        """
        Connects all the nodes with undirected edges, meaning each pair of nodes are connected to each other
        forms n(n+1)/2 edges in total
        """
        nodes = self.graph.keys()
        comb = itertools.combinations(nodes, 2)
        for node1, node2 in comb:
            self.create_undirected_edge(node1, node2)


    def is_nodes_connected(self, node1, node2):
        if self.check_node_exist(node1) and self.check_node_exist(node2):
            if node1 in self.graph[node2] and node2 in self.graph[node1]:
                return True
            return False


    def connections(self, node):
        """
        returns the connected/adjacent nodes of a given node
        """
        return self.graph[node] if self.check_node_exist(node) else None


    def is_undirected_graph(self):
        """
        checks whether every edge in the graph is undirected/ by checking every node and their connections
        """
        for node, connections in self.graph.items():
            for connected_node in connections:
                if node not in self.graph[connected_node]:
                    return False
        return True


    def create_edge_list(self):
        """
        creates and returns an edge list, with tuples representing the edges between the pair of nodes, in each tuple.
        """ # makes sure that the graph is undirected
        arr = set()
        nodes = self.graph.keys()
        for node in nodes:
            for connected_node in self.graph[node]:
                arr.add((node, connected_node))
        return arr


    def create_adjacency_list(self):
        """
        creates and returns an adjacency list, in the format "node ---> connected_node1 connected_node2, etc"
        """
        return self.__str__()


    def create_adjacency_matrix(self):
        """
        creates and returns an adjacency matrix

        indexing dict, contains keys-value pairs in which indexes refer to their node

        FORMAT: for nodes 1, 2, 3 in an undirected graph
            {0: node1, 1: node2, 2: node3}
            [(0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0)]
        """
        nodes = list(self.graph.keys())
        indexing_dict = {i: nodes[i] for i in range(len(nodes))}
        adjacency_matrix = {tuple(1 if nodes[j] in self.graph[indexing_dict[i]] else 0 for j in range(self.num_of_nodes)) for i in range(self.num_of_nodes)}
        return f"{indexing_dict}\n{adjacency_matrix}"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Dict literals

```
    self.graph = dict()
```

can be

```
    self.graph = {}
```

### Intermediate `list` before `join`

```
    arr = list()
    for node, connected_nodes in self.graph.items():
        arr.append(f"{node} ---> {' '.join(list(map(str, connected_nodes)))}")
    return "\n".join(arr)
```

can be

```
arr = (
    f"{node} ---> {' '.join(str(n) for n in connected_nodes)}"
    for node, connected_nodes in self.graph.items()
)
return "\n".join(arr)
```

This will use a couple of generators directly instead of outer and inner lists.

### True-or-exception

The return model for `check_node_exist` - either returning `True` or raising an exception - is curious. You should go "all or nothing": either return True/False - or "throw an exception or don't".

### Direct return of boolean expressions

```
        if node1 in self.graph[node2] and node2 in self.graph[node1]:
            return True
        return False
```

can be

```
return node1 in self.graph[node2] and node2 in self.graph[node1]
```

### Set comprehension

```
    arr = set()
    nodes = self.graph.keys()
    for node in nodes:
        for connected_node in self.graph[node]:
            arr.add((node, connected_node))
    return arr
```

can be

```
return {
    (node, connected_node)
    for node in self.graph.keys()
    for connected_node in self.graph[node]
}
```

### Calling dunder methods

```
return self.__str__()
```

should be

```
return str(self)
```

Comment: wow i had no idea you could do use formatted strings in comprehensions +1

Answer (score 2):

I think create_edge_list/create_adjacency_list naming is a bit inconsistent, one returns a list as you would expect, the other returns a string representation.

Comment: that is true, perhaps i should make them both iterables